# How to get json result with parent - child relation?(see details)

Tags: node.js

I have two json one is parent and another is child, I want to merge both. Please help. See the example below

**Two tables are as below.**

```
var parent = [{id : 1, name : 'India'},
            {id : 2, name : 'USA'},
            {id : 3, name : 'Japan'},
            {id : 4, name : 'UK'}]

var child = [{id: 1, parentId: 1, city : 'Ahmedabad', population:100},
             {id: 2, parentId: 1, city : 'Mumbai', population:200},
             {id: 3, parentId: 2, city : 'NewYork', population:300},
             {id: 4, parentId: 2, city : 'Chicago', population:400},
             {id: 5, parentId: 3, city : 'Tokyo', population:500}]
```

**I want to result like below**

```
var result = 
[{id : 1, name : 'India', city:[{name : 'Ahmedabad', population:100},{name : 'Mumbai', population:200}]},
{id : 2, name : 'USA', city:[{name : 'NewYork', population:300},{name : 'Chicago', population:400}]},
{id : 3, name : 'Japan', city:[{name : 'Tokyo', population:500}]},
{id : 4, name : 'UK', city:[]}
]
```

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: I have two tables one parent and another child. I want to json of both data as described. With the select query I took parent table data and child data. With loop we can add child data into parent but I face problem. I need simple and easy logic to implement it. These are dummy data.

Comment: I did not ask you to repeat your description of what you want, but to show us your attempt. _"With loop we can add child data into parent but I face problem"_ - **show us**, instead of telling us a story ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parent));

result.map(function (d, i) {
  d.city = (child.filter(function (d1) {
    if (d1.parentId == d.id) {
      return  d1;
    }
  })).map(function(d2){
    return {city:d2.city,population:d2.population}
  });
})
```

Now result variable contains your expected result.